# Using custom http header for NTLM authentication in Odata Connected Service in visual studio 2019

Tags: odata-connected-service

This is first time I am trying something outside my work area. I normally work on D365 business central . I am trying to consume a webservice exposed on Dynamics Business Central in visual studio 2019 using Odata Conneted service but I am getting error 401 i.e. unauthorized. while the same is working perfectly fine when I try with Postman. Please help to know where I m going wrong. Thanks a lot in advance. Here is the screen shot of Odata Connetected Service I m trying

[Odata Connected End Point Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix6FD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same issue. My workaroud was to download the .edmx-file behind the *$metadata*-URL with a browser. This should also work with Postman.

Then in Visual Studio instead of unserting the URL use *Browse* and navigate to your .edmx-file.